# Loading javascript asychronously with dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to load my javascript file with the following code

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var arr = new Array();
  arr[0] = "/js/main.js";
  arr[1] = "/js/jquery.expander.min.js";
  arr[2] = "/js/custom_expander.js";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
      var tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.type = "text/javascript";
      tag.async = true;
      tag.src = arr[i];
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
  }
};
```

It's working well but my problem is that my third file (custom_expander.js) depends on the second (jquery.expander.min.js).
That's mostly why custom_expander.js is third in the list by the way.

However, even with this code, I have the following error

```
TypeError: $(...).expander is not a function
```

This error is here because my custom_expander.js loaded before jquery.expander.min.js finished loading. When the files are loaded synchronously like below, there's no error.

```
<script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.expander.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/custom_expander.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I had the exact same problem when I wanted to load jquery asynchronously and I've decided to keep it in my  tag but it's not a solution.

How can I do to load javascript files asynchronously when there's dependencies between files ?

Comment: Or any other module loader really, you don't have to implement this yourself there are a lot of libraries that do a good job and handle edge cases.

Comment: Use promises (then) to load them one by one ?

Comment: When you use `defer` or `asyc` attribute in `script` its common. If you remove tag.async in your code it will work. Also it's better to go with module loaders like require.js or steal.js etc...

Comment: @mohamedrias I don't think removing `async` will work because he is injecting script. If script is downloaded using script injection, it is always async.

Comment: If you use jQuery try with [jQuery's .getScript() method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), so you can load your scripts in the order you want.

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in above comments, if you are working with jQuery, you can use the `$.getScript()` method ([jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/))

Here is an example (try it with your own scripts at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/7fwfmvsx/)):

```
var MyApp = {

    Scripts: {

        // put them with the correct order
        ToLoad: [
            '/path/to/script1.js',
            '/path/to/script2.js',
            '/path/to/script3.js'
        ],

        Loaded: 0

    },

    DoTheJob: function(){
        if( this.Scripts.ToLoad.length == this.Scripts.Loaded ) return;
        $.getScript(this.Scripts.ToLoad[this.Scripts.Loaded], function(){
            MyApp.Scripts.Loaded++;
            MyApp.DoTheJob();
        });
    }

};

// do it on ready (faster way)
$(function(){ 
    MyApp.DoTheJob();
});

// or do it on load
//window.onload = function(){ 
//    MyApp.DoTheJob();
//});
```

Remember that you can improve it with a handler when all scripts have been loaded.

Comment: I just tried your solution but unfortunatly, it doesn't work. There are two main reason to that. 1) $.getScript is an alias for $.ajax and $.ajax is asynchronous which mean that it'll not always load the files in the order specified. 2) Even if you set `async=false`, files are still interpreted asynchronously. It means that file A can be interpreted after file B even if the file a is requested before file B. it depends on file A and file B size.

Comment: It's strange, because this code loads a script and, only when that script is already loaded, it loads the next script, like a loop. I'll take a look in real environment.

Comment: I tried it and it works correctly. I tried to load 3 scripts and each one loads in the expected order, so the code works. Forget the jsFiddle, try it in your real environment, or use a single file, but always through a web server. Use the browser dev tools (network tab) and see how it loads in the expected order.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use RequireJs.It's cool thing.I think you will like it.it's not difficult

Comment: Please consider to use *comments* for comments.